# Who discovered the first explicit formula for the n-th prime?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, math-history

I just found out on Wolfram that there is a formula for the n-th prime in terms of elementary functions. I wonder who found it and if he was rewarded for this. The formula ([here](http://www4f.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP27520d669fe52cie1f1000033cec14b3c2eh7ac?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=38&w=380.&h=186.)) is:

[image]

Also shown at 
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=prime(n)

Comment: This [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/940338/the-myth-of-no-prime-formula/940619#940619) is relevant.  The answer of Dan Petersen, in particular, contains a link to a nice article by Underwood Dudley that contains some history.

Comment: If he was "rewarded"?

Comment: The formula here doesn't actually give any insight into computing the $n$th prime efficiently, all it does is encode (obfuscate?) the process of trial division, or something related, into an unreadable mathematical expression. The presence of floor operations and sums (which are a cute but in this context uninteresting way to emulate conditionals and loops) give it away.

Comment: If "he" was rewarded?

Comment: It is not elementary functions.

Comment: As soon as I looked at it, I immediately guessed that the formula was obtained by Ramanujan. Is this reasonable thinking?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are many formulas for the $n$th prime.
The only really useful ones are in the form of fast computer programs
(yes, those are formulas too, just not what you would normally consider a
"closed-form" formula of elementary functions).

Consider the formula in question here,

[image]

Observe that in order to find the $n$th prime, this formula requires you to
compute $2^n$ terms of the sum. Hence as an algorithm it is of order $\Omega(2^n)$,
which is pretty bad.

In addition to the question [The myth of no prime formula?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/940338/139123) already cited in a comment,
see the following

- [What would be the immediate implications of a formula for prime numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/392442/139123)
- [Any formula for the exact number of primes below a given bound](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1117103/139123)
- [Can insight be derived from direct formulae for prime number functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/44290/139123)
- [Formula for the nth prime number: discovered?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/88033/139123)

Answer (score 19):

Here is something that I have established a long time ago. It doesn't answer your question directly, but rather illustrates the fact that one can easily establish such formula (the one below is given by $P_n$). The real challenge is to establish a prime-formula which is not "computationally worthless".

---

**Is $n$ prime:**

$$F_n=\left\lfloor\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{k=2}^{n-1}\left\lceil\frac{{n}\bmod{k}}{n}\right\rceil\right)+2\cdot\left\lceil\frac{n-1}{n}\right\rceil}{n}\right\rfloor$$

---

**How many primes until $n$:**

$$G_n=\sum\limits_{k=2}^{n}F_k$$

---

**What is the $n$th prime number:**

$$P_n=\sum\limits_{k=n}^{n^2+1}{k}\cdot{F_k}\cdot\left(1-\left\lceil\frac{(G_k-n)^2}{(G_k+n)^2}\right\rceil\right)$$

Comment: This is more like a computer program rather than a closed-form formula...

Comment: @Mehrdad: That is precisely what I was implying at the beginning (top part) of the answer. BTW, I'm not sure that there even exists a definition that accurately distinguishes between a computer program and a closed-form formula (i.e., every computer program can be converted into a formula and vice-versa).

Comment: I mean, it would be a lot cooler if you could do the same thing in terms of mathematically "nice" functions (e.g. perhaps smoother... no floors/ceilings/absolute values/etc.). And yeah, I don't think there's a rigorous distinction between the two... it's an "I know it when I see it" kind of thing.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Yep. And in addition to that, unless you can provide a mathematical definition of the term "nice", it remains subjected to personal perspective.

Comment: How about nice = elementary?

Comment: @Mehrdad: And elementary = ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function